# How to Wrap a RelayContainer with a regular React Container?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs

I want to automate adding a `<Layout />` container component to all my `<View />` components.

In this scenario, the `Layout` component doesn't know which `View` it is going to get, so I can't apply `Relay.createContainer` to the `Layout` since I don't have the relay container spec at declaration.

Because the `View` is wrapped by the `Layout`, the `RelayRootContainer.component` receives the Layout component, which is a non-relay container, and of course, it throws an error.

This is my Layout component:

```
export default class MainLayout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        {this.props.children}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

After adding the Relay capabilities to the View, it now looks like this.

```
class HomeView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <ul>
      {this.props.store.posts.map(post =>
        <li key={post.id}>
          {post.name}
        </li>
      }
    </ul>
  }
}

const RelayHomeView = Relay.createContainer(HomeView, {
  fragments: {
    store: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Store {
        posts {
            id,
            name,
        }
      }
    `
  }
});

export default RelayHomeView;
```

I came up with two possible work-arounds:

1. Use a high order component Layout and declare the Relay Container Specs as a static property in the View. However, this breaks the convention of exporting an already built relay container
2. Wrap the render View in the Layout component. Unfortunately this adds a lot of boilerplate by having to import and wrap all views in a component